# Apache reverse proxy not rendering angular builds's javascript to the client

Tags: angularjs, apache, apache2, devops

I am Trying to implement reverse proxy for my 2 sites but from one of them is not rendering html .

Below is my configuration file for apache ssl config

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName xxxx.xxxx.org

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                ProxyPreserveHost off
                SSLProxyEngine On
                SSLProxyVerify none
                SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
                SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
                SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
                <Proxy *>
                        Order deny,allow
                        Allow from all
                </Proxy>
                <Location />
                        ProxyPass https://localhost:3000/
                        ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:3000/
                </Location>
                <Location /app1>

                        ProxyPass  http://localhost:4200/
                        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:4200/

                </Location>

                # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
                # error, crit, alert, emerg.
                # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
                # modules, e.g.
                #LogLevel info ssl:warn

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
                # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
                # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
                # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
                # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
                #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

                #   SSL Engine Switch:
                #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
                SSLEngine on

                #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
                #   the ssl-cert package. See
                #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
                #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
                #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl-certificate/xxxxxccc.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl-certificate/xxxx.xxxx.org.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl-certificate/sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

Now I am trying to access my server with `https://xxx.fghjk.org/app1` but it's showing blank page . I observed that this page is not able to load java script files build by angular application .

Any suggestion apperciated

Comment: If you inspect in browser developer console, what is the url of unrendered file, and what would be the path of that file if you try to fetch it directly from :4200?

Comment: https://server/runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js  @DusanBajic

Comment: http://server.org:4200/runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js able to see the content here

Comment: Well, mod proxy will not change references in your app's html content, so you need to either use relative path to .js files, or use mod_substitute (or something similar), to rewrite those references (to add leading `/app1`)

Comment: i didn't get you . what about mod_proxy_html @DusanBajic

Comment: yes, it should do the job (that is why i said "or something similar" :), I just found mod_substitute to be easier to configure )

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic . I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is most likely due to the references that angular uses to retrieve the js and css files from the `index.html`. In a setup like yours it is thus necessary to set the `<base>` tag in `index.html`.

In your case it would need to be `<base href="/app1">`.

See https://angular.io/guide/deployment for more details or alternatives how to set the base url appropriately.